# Get URL var in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Hello I have a page with a url like

mypage.com?iid=11&pid=1

In there im running some ajax and need to pass the idd from my querystring to this code block

```
$.ajax({
dataType : "html" ,
url: "stream.php?iid=[GET iid]&lastComment="+ $(".postedComment:last").attr('id') ,
```

But am not experienced enough with JS to get my syntax correct. What would i use in place of [GET iid] to pass that variable?

```
<?php $_GET['iid'];?>
```

won't work since its a JS file.

Thanks

Comment: The concatenation in the url isn't the essence. As a whole it can very well be said a duplicate. I vote to close too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard solution. Everyone has his own solution.

Personally I sometimes use this function :

```
getUrlParameter = function(name, defaultValue) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var results = new RegExp( "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)" )
         .exec( document.location.href );
    if( results == null ) return defaultValue;
    else return decodeURIComponent(results[1]);
};
```

like this :

```
$.ajax({
dataType : "html" ,
url: "stream.php?iid="+getUrlParameter('iid')+"&lastComment="+ $(".postedComment:last").attr('id') ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: Vote to close as a duplicate (or flag for the mods) instead of copy+pasting the code here. But thanks for the research :-)